# Wordpress custom field date, display post with custom date > current in ascending order

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

How do I order post by a custom field if "releasedate" > "currentdate" but in acending order. Basically only display post with dates starting after today but in ascending order. currently i have

```
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=10&post_type=movies&meta_key=releasedate_value&orderby=releasedate_value&order=ASC');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
?>


<?php if ($releasedate >  $currentdate) {?>
```

"my contents/ post here"

```
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

now everything works except when its ASC and not DSC, no post will display because wordpress in getting the post first and the erasing the post that are not before current date and only 10 post are allowed, therefore if 10 post has a release date before today, wordpress loads then erase them after and leaves everything blank! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd put the date criteria into the query itself.  Assuming you have WordPress version 3.1 or higher, you can use the [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) parameter.  Something like:

```
<?php
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));

$wp_query = new WP_Query(  array ('showposts' => 10,
                'post_type' => 'movies',
                'meta_query'=> array(
                    array(
                      'key' => 'releasedate_value',
                      'compare' => '>',
                      'value' => $currentdate,
                      'type' => 'DATE',
                    )),
                'meta_key' => 'releasedate_value',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

This works with me too:

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));

                                    $args =  array(
                                        'post_type' => 'event',
                                        'meta_key'  => 'date_field',
                                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                        'order' => 'ASC',
                                        'meta_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                'key' => 'date_field',
                                                'value' => $currentdate,
                                                'compare' => '>=',
                                                'type' => 'DATE'
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    );
                                    $my_query = null;
                                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```